# Azure DevOps - Linking Class Library project into the release of another project

Tags: azure-devops

Under same ORG, i have 2 projects. One is a class library project. Another one is a web site project. Both have their own build and release definition. I want to include dlls from the class library project when i do a release of the web site project. Web site project uses IIS deployment tasks in it's release. This IIS deployment task deploy the zip file created from the build of the web site project only (this project will have reference of the dll from class library already added). What i need is when the release of web site happen , it should pick the latest dll from class library project added in to it's bin folder. How do i do that in devops release definition.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure DevOps - Linking Class Library project into the release of another project

The easiest way is add the class library project in the solution of web site project and set it as project reference instead of reference the dll file.

Then we build the solution of the web site project, the latest dll from class library project will be added in to bin folder of web site project each time when we build the solution.

If you do not want to use project refernce, you can also use the [Download Pipeline Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) task in the build pipeline of web site project to download the latest dll from class library project, then use the [Copy Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task to copy the dll from the default folder to the `bin` folder.

Hope this helps.